# Aplicativo ionic em diferentes versões do android

Tags: android, ionic, mobile

Estou tendo um problema em criar uma apk que rode em versões diferentes do android. Meu celular tem a versão 6.0.1 e roda perfeitamente mas quando tentei instalar em um android 5.0.2 o aplicativo abriu mas a tela ficou em branco.
Até o momento construia os aplicativos usando:

```
ionic cordova platform add android
ionic cordova build android
```

Creio que esses comandos sem parametros a mais crie uma apk com a versao mais atualizada. Gostaria de diminuir a versão minima do sdk suportada para versão 5.0.2, ou fazer uma build especifica para essa versão.

Comando que tentei:

```
ionic cordova platform add android@5.0.0
```

Até construiu mas na hora de gerar a apk da o seguinte erro:

```
> cordova build android
cordova-android-support-gradle-release: Android platform: cordova-android@6
cordova-android-support-gradle-release: Wrote custom version '27.+' to C:\Users\Marketing\Documents\ionic\Orcamento\platforms\android\build.gradle
cordova-android-support-gradle-release: ERROR: EXCEPTION: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\Marketing\Documents\ionic\Orcamento\platforms\android\cordova-android-support-gradle-release\properties.gradle'
cordova-android-support-gradle-release: Android platform: cordova-android@6
cordova-android-support-gradle-release: Wrote custom version '27.+' to C:\Users\Marketing\Documents\ionic\Orcamento\platforms\android\build.gradle
cordova-android-support-gradle-release: ERROR: EXCEPTION: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\Marketing\Documents\ionic\Orcamento\platforms\android\cordova-android-support-gradle-release\properties.gradle'
(node:1496) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: CordovaError: Android SDK not found. Make sure that it is installed. If it is not at the default location, set the ANDROID_HOME environment variable.
    at C:\Users\Marketing\Documents\ionic\Orcamento\platforms\android\cordova\lib\check_reqs.js:45:27
    at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:282:5)
    at emitTwo (events.js:126:13)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:214:7)
    at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:925:16)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:209:5)
(node:1496) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
(node:1496) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

- Tentei mudar manualmente o '27.+' para uma versão inferior mas sem
  sucesso ela retornava após a construção falhar.
- Também baixei a API do android 5 no sdk manager pelo android studio.

Quem puder ajudar eu agradeço desde já.

Comment: Dependendo dos plugins que estiveres usando, é impossível dar suporte a versões anteriores do Android.

Comment: Obrigado por responder, sim tenho ciência que dependendo do plugin instalado não terá suporte, entretanto a plataforma é gerada então os problemas não estão no plugin.